# MongoDB group data melt

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have a small dataset:

```
[
    {"A": 0, "B": 0, "X": 100, "Y": 100},
    {"A": 1, "B": 0, "X": 50, "Y": 55},
    {"A": 0, "B": 1, "X": 25, "Y": 30},
    {"A": 1, "B": 1, "X": 1, "Y": 6}
]
```

I also have a pipeline where the final stage is a group:

```
[
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "classification1": {
                    "$eq": ["$A", 1]
                },
                "classification2": {
                    "$eq": ["$B", 1]
                }
            },
            "countX": {"$sum": "$X"},
            "countY": {"$sum": "$Y"}
        }
    }
]
```

The output of this pipeline:

```
[
    {"_id": {"classification1": false, "classification2": false}, "countX": 100, "countY": 100},
    {"_id": {"classification1": true, "classification2": false}, "countX": 50, "countY": 55},
    {"_id": {"classification1": false, "classification2": true}, "countX": 25, "countY": 30},
    {"_id": {"classification1": true, "classification2": true}, "countX": 1, "countY": 6}
]
```

What pipeline steps would I need to reach a melted format like this?

```
[
    {"name": "classification1", "countX": 51, "countY": 61},
    {"name": "classification2", "countX": 26, "countY": 36}
]
```

Note that this transformation counts document 1 from the previous stage zero times, and counts document 4 twice (since both conditions are false, or both are true).

I have written a Javascript function for this, but Javascript functions cannot be invoked from the pipeline (aggregation pipelines must be serializable). Unfortunately, that means I have to unload the data from the DB, run the script on the data, and then load the transformed data back in as a temporary collection to finish the rest of the pipeline after this stage.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some reading on facets. Somewhat verbose, but this query provides melted data in the proper format:

```
[
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "classification1": {
                    "$eq": ["$A", 1]
                },
                "classification2": {
                    "$eq": ["$B", 1]
                }
            },
            "countX": {"$sum": "$X"},
            "countY": {"$sum": "$Y"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "classification1": [
                {"$match": {"_id.classification1": true}},
                {"$group": {"_id": null, "X": {"$sum": "$countX"}, "Y": {"$sum": "$countY"}}},
                {"$addFields": {"name": "classification1"}}
            ],
            "classification2": [
                {"$match": {"_id.classification2": true}},
                {"$group": {"_id": null, "X": {"$sum": "$countX"}, "Y": {"$sum": "$countY"}}},
                {"$addFields": {"name": "classification2"}}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {"combine": {"$setUnion": ["$classification1", "$classification2"]}}
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$combine"
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$combine"}
    },
    {
        "$project": {"_id": 0}
    }
]
```